# JavaScript and the seach input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a bunch of cards, each card contains ul (the same class name for all) and each ul has three li (the same class name for all, plus the color name, example `<li class="card-li black">Black</li>`) 

Now all I need to do is to hide the cards that don't contain the color name in the `li` when I search for it. for example, when I search for the color Black, the 3rd card should `display: none`. And when I clear the search, all the cards get back to the normal display.

```css
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {.container {max-width: 540px;}}
@media (min-width: 768px) {.container {max-width: 760px;}}
@media (min-width: 992px) {.container {max-width: 960px;}}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {.container {max-width: 1190px;}}

.form-container {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 30px 0;
}

.search-input {
    width: 250px;
    height: 30px;
}

.card {
    background-color: #ddd;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0 1%;
    height: 100px;
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.card:hover .card-ul {
    transform: translateX(0%);
}

.card-ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.card-li {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-container">
        <form id="search-form">
            <input type="search" class="search-input">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
            <ul class="card-ul">
                <li class="card-li black">Black</li>
                <li class="card-li red">Red</li>
                <li class="card-li white">White</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <ul class="card-ul">
                <li class="card-li black">Black</li>
                <li class="card-li yellow">Yellow</li>
                <li class="card-li blue">Blue</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <ul class="card-ul">
                <li class="card-li green">Green</li>
                <li class="card-li purple">Purple</li>
                <li class="card-li white">White</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My original code:

```
<div class="card">
    <a href="">
        <div class="img-div">
            <img class="img" src="...">
            <div class="desc">
                <ul class="tags-ul">
                    <li class="tag-li black">Black</li>
                    <li class="tag-li yellow">Yellow</li>
                    <li class="tag-li jwhite">White</li>
                </ul>
                <p>text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
            <p>text</p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Is jQuery an option?

Comment: I'm working on a project using Vanilla JS

Comment: Can you include the JS?

Comment: Actually that's what I'm trying to figure it out! I need a function to check if the card's `li` class name has the color that been searched for in the search input.
For example, when I search for black, the 3rd card should `display: none` because it doesn't have the class name 'black'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I attached [keyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keyup_event) event on the search term and once user input a string javascript will disable all cards using `toggleDisplay()` function, and then search/loop through li using [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) that match the search term and if `<li>` content text matched it will only toggle style display to its parent using [`.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

Here is what I think you are looking for

```js
document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  let term = e.target.value;
  if(term) {

    toggleDisplay('none')    
    let elements = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
    for(let i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
       if(elements[i].textContent.includes(term)) {
         elements[i].closest('.card').style.display = 'block';
       }
    }
  }
  else {
    toggleDisplay('inline-block')
  }
});

function toggleDisplay(display) {
  let cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
  for(let i=0; i< cards.length; i++){
    cards[i].style.display = display;
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {.container {max-width: 540px;}}
@media (min-width: 768px) {.container {max-width: 760px;}}
@media (min-width: 992px) {.container {max-width: 960px;}}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {.container {max-width: 1190px;}}

.form-container {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 30px 0;
}

.search-input {
    width: 250px;
    height: 30px;
}

.card {
    background-color: #ddd;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0 1%;
    height: 100px;
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.card:hover .card-ul {
    transform: translateX(0%);
}

.card-ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.3s;
    
}

.card-li {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-container">
        <form id="search-form">
            <input type="text" id="search" class="search-input">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
          <a href="">
              <div class="img-div">
                  <img class="img" src="...">
                  <div class="desc">
                      <ul class="card-ul">
                          <li class="card-li black">Black</li>
                          <li class="card-li yellow">Yellow</li>
                          <li class="card-li jwhite">White</li>
                      </ul>
                      <p>text</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="title">
                  <p>text</p>
              </div>
          </a>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
          <a href="">
              <div class="img-div">
                  <img class="img" src="...">
                  <div class="desc">
                      <ul class="card-ul">
                          <li class="card-li black">Red</li>
                          <li class="card-li yellow">Green</li>
                          <li class="card-li jwhite">White</li>
                      </ul>
                      <p>text</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="title">
                  <p>text</p>
              </div>
          </a>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
          <a href="">
              <div class="img-div">
                  <img class="img" src="...">
                  <div class="desc">
                      <ul class="card-ul">
                          <li class="card-li black">Denim</li>
                          <li class="card-li yellow">Amaranth</li>
                          <li class="card-li jwhite">Celadon</li>
                      </ul>
                      <p>text</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="title">
                  <p>text</p>
              </div>
          </a>
      </div>
       <div class="card">
          <a href="">
              <div class="img-div">
                  <img class="img" src="...">
                  <div class="desc">
                      <ul class="card-ul">
                          <li class="card-li black">Brown</li>
                          <li class="card-li yellow">Capri</li>
                          <li class="card-li jwhite">Camel</li>
                      </ul>
                      <p>text</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="title">
                  <p>text</p>
              </div>
          </a>
      </div>
       <div class="card">
          <a href="">
              <div class="img-div">
                  <img class="img" src="...">
                  <div class="desc">
                      <ul class="card-ul">
                          <li class="card-li black">Brown</li>
                          <li class="card-li yellow">Blond</li>
                          <li class="card-li jwhite">Blue</li>
                      </ul>
                      <p>text</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="title">
                  <p>text</p>
              </div>
          </a>
      </div>
       <div class="card">
          <a href="">
              <div class="img-div">
                  <img class="img" src="...">
                  <div class="desc">
                      <ul class="card-ul">
                          <li class="card-li black">Beaver</li>
                          <li class="card-li yellow">Aqua</li>
                          <li class="card-li jwhite">Pink</li>
                      </ul>
                      <p>text</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="title">
                  <p>text</p>
              </div>
          </a>
      </div>
       <div class="card">
          <a href="">
              <div class="img-div">
                  <img class="img" src="...">
                  <div class="desc">
                      <ul class="card-ul">
                          <li class="card-li black">Amber</li>
                          <li class="card-li yellow">Apricot</li>
                          <li class="card-li jwhite">Amethyst</li>
                      </ul>
                      <p>text</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="title">
                  <p>text</p>
              </div>
          </a>
      </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works here, but since I have more divs and links in the cards in my original code, it doesn't work, it sets all the cards to `display: none`

Comment: @Joseph, can you reproduce it in your question? that would make it easy to spot the issue, since here its working.

Comment: @Joseph, I edited the snippet, `elements[i].closest('.card').style.display = 'block';` this is the line to change, please test and let me know if it didn't work.

Comment: I have 9 cards (will be more soon), each card has at least one li (color), I've tried the code, it worked only with one card, the others didn't work. for example, when I type black, it shows me the card that has the color black, but it doesn't work if I search for another color

Comment: @Joseph, I added the same HTML structure, its working without issues, not sure what the issue is, can you make a fiddle and link it here?

Comment: I have more `li` tags on the page for other lists that are not related to the cards even!! that's why it didn't work well! So I changed the `let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.card-li');`

Thank you so much :)!

Comment: Ty bro, I appreciate that!

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the list of cards, and add the `.hide` class to all of them. Then iterate the list of `.card-li` items, and find their parent card using `Element.closest()`. Remove the `.hide` class from the card.

```js
const searchInput = document.querySelector('.search-input')
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card')

const toggleVisibility = colorName => {
  cards.forEach(c => c.classList.add('hide'))
  
  document.querySelectorAll(`.card-li${colorName ? `.${colorName}`: ''}`)
    .forEach(c => c.closest('.card').classList.remove('hide'))
}

searchInput.addEventListener('input', e => toggleVisibility(String(e.target.value || '')))
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 540px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 760px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 960px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1190px;
  }
}

.form-container {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.search-input {
  width: 250px;
  height: 30px;
}

.card {
  background-color: #ddd;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 1%;
  height: 100px;
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card:hover .card-ul {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.card-ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.card-li {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-container">
    <form id="search-form">
      <input type="search" class="search-input">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card">
      <ul class="card-ul">
        <li class="card-li black">Black</li>
        <li class="card-li red">Red</li>
        <li class="card-li white">White</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <ul class="card-ul">
        <li class="card-li black">Black</li>
        <li class="card-li yellow">Yellow</li>
        <li class="card-li blue">Blue</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <ul class="card-ul">
        <li class="card-li green">Green</li>
        <li class="card-li purple">Purple</li>
        <li class="card-li white">White</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works. The only problem I can think of is with uppercase letters. Try now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {.container {max-width: 540px;}}
@media (min-width: 768px) {.container {max-width: 760px;}}
@media (min-width: 992px) {.container {max-width: 960px;}}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {.container {max-width: 1190px;}}

.form-container {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 30px 0;
}

.search-input {
    width: 250px;
    height: 30px;
}

.card {
    background-color: #ddd;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0 1%;
    height: 100px;
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.card:hover .card-ul {
    transform: translateX(0%);
}

.card-ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.card-li {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.green{
background:green;
}
.red{
background:red;
}
.blue{
background:blue;
}
.white{
background:white;
}
.purple{
background:purple;
}

.yellow{
background:yellow;
}
.black{
background:black;
}
.hide{
display:none
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-container">
        <form id="search-form">
            <input type="search" class="search-input">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
            <ul class="card-ul">
                <li class="card-li black">Black</li>
                <li class="card-li red">Red</li>
                <li class="card-li white">White</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <ul class="card-ul">
                <li class="card-li black">Black</li>
                <li class="card-li yellow">Yellow</li>
                <li class="card-li blue">Blue</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <ul class="card-ul">
                <li class="card-li green">Green</li>
                <li class="card-li purple">Purple</li>
                <li class="card-li white">White</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 <script>
const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('change', updateValue);

function updateValue(e) {
  let value = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  document.querySelectorAll(".card").forEach(v=>{
  let allList = v.innerText.toLowerCase();
    if(allList.includes(value)){
       v.classList.add("hide");
    }
  })
}
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```